# PhpStorm unused property warning using res.json in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpstorm, jsdoc

I have these 2 functions in `AssessmentController.js`:

```js
/**
 * Get all assessments
 *
 * @param req
 * @param res
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 */
static async GetAll(req, res) {
    try {
        let assessments = await Assessment.GetAll(req.query);
        res.json({
            msg: 'Assessments were listed successfully.',
            assessments //This is marked as unused property
        });
    } catch (err) {
        CustomError.handle(err, res);
    }
}

/**
 * Get a single assessment
 *
 * @param req
 * @param res
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 */
static async GetAssessment(req, res) {
    try {
        let assessment = await Assessment.GetAssessment(req.params.id);
        res.json({
            msg: 'Assessment is retrieved successfully',
            assessment //This is NOT marked as unused property
        })
    } catch (err) {
        CustomError.handle(err, res);
    }
}
```

The return types in JSDoc of the functions `GetAll` and `GetAssessment` are `@returns {Promise<Object[]>}` and `@returns {Promise<Object>}` respectively.

I don't know why passing `assessments` property to `res.json` in the first function (`GetAll`) triggers unused variable although this is not happening in the second function (`GetAssessment`).

Please let me know in the comments if you need any more information as I don't know where exactly to look for the problem.

Here is a snapshot of what I'm seeing:
[image]

**NOTE:**
Even if I don't use shorthand property (`assessments: assessments`) I get the warning.
[image]

I have also discovered just now that if I rename the variable to `assessment` (Singular) the warning is gone, how can I trace this problem?

Another example, it happens very randomly and I am showing images to see what I'm facing:
[image]

Maybe it is an IDE bug?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is tracked at [WEB-38106](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38106), please follow it for updates

Comment: But even if I use the longhand property `assessments: assessments` I get unused property, it's not about using shorthand property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
assessments: assessments
```

instead of `assessments`.

Maybe your ide doesn't understand it.